# Questions about using Disqus or Jetpack for comments

Tags: plugins, comments, comment-form, plugin-jetpack, disqus

I'm looking for a good commenting plugin, I want to choose between Disqus and Jetpack, but I have a few questions I **couldn't** figure out myself.

Hopefully you guys can help me out! :)

1) Where are the comments stored, is this in my database on or the Disqus/jetpack server?

2) What will happen if I switch over to default comments after all, will the Disqus or jetpack comments be removed?

3)Facebook is really important, while loggin in on Jetpack/Disqus, will these comment show up on facebook (in the activity feed of their friends) as well? Like normal facebook comments in wordpress?

4) Same with twitter, is there an option to share the comment on Twitter?

Hope you guys can help. Thanks.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think you are wrong. I deleted the post myself accidently. So after that I decided to ask it again, since there weren't any answers after all. But now there are :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Disqus and can anwser for this platform :

1) You have the option to save comments both on Disqus and locally on WordPress.

2) This way, if you want to switch to default comments, they will already be there. On the other side, you cal also import local comments to Disqus, if you were using the default comment system and want to switch to Disqus.

3,4) You can share your comment once created, you can test this yourself on any disqus enabled website

Comment: Cool :) Do not hesitate to mark my answer as correct if that helped. Good luck in your project